# How to know which fields were updated

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working in laravel 5, I have a module where the user can update the information of students, for that The user has a preloaded form with the current data and he can modify the fields that he wants.Then, in the controller I do:

```
$perfil->update(Input::all())
```

That works pretty good. So my question is: there's a way of get the name of the fields that have been updated?

Comment: create field modified date on database, and update this date always. So you can check which fields been updated

Comment: No, I have already a field updated_at but that is updated everytime that something of the register changes.That doesn't tell me which fields were modified. For the otherside,I you mean to create a field *modified* for every field that is not elegant and not even correct. Thanks

Comment: One of my projects I have to monitor the changes so I did table to changes and has unique id uid() - then I did table for fields (change_id, field, new_value) - I hope you got my idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the dirty() method. this has been explained well here.

[Laravel Eloquent update just if changes have been made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866500/laravel-eloquent-update-just-if-changes-have-been-made)

Comment: i think getDirty() will be empty once the update is performed, its best suitable when the query is not performed yet. getChanges() get the changed properties after the update is performed.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `getChanges()` on Eloquent model even after persisting.

```
$offer->update($data);
$offer->getChanges(); // [ "price_min" => "1233",  "updated_at" => "2019-01-10 15:36:23"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function that can be used to obtain, in array format, the changes but only for fillable attributes of the model:

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public function getFillableChanges(): array
    {
        return array_intersect_key($this->getChanges(), array_flip($this->getFillable()));
    }
}
```

This function is included in an abstract class and Model classes can extend it, or the function can be copied inside the Model class for which he has a use:

Later, the function can be used like this:

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);

$fillableChanges = $flight->getFillableChanges();
```