# Laravel update record where something has been changed

Tags: laravel, updates

I want write method to update records where something has been changed. I have forms:
[image]

The problem is when I change the name, surname or email but don't change the user login. In my validation I write:

```
'name' => ['required', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
```

But the rule `unique:users` blocks me from updating when I haven't changed the user name.

I found this theme [Laravel 5 isDirty() always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329850/laravel-5-isdirty-always-returns-false?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but I dont understand what is "`$partnersData`". `$partnersData` is a date last update ?

I wrote this method:

```
public function update(CreateUserUpdateRequest $request, $id){
    $user = User::find($id);

    foreach ($user as $column => $value) {
        if ($column === $id) {
            continue;
        }
        $user->$column = $value;
    }

    if ($user->isDirty()) {
        $user->update($request->all());
        Session::flash('userUpdateOK', 'Dane użytkonika zostały zaktualizowane poprawnie.');
    }

    return redirect('user');
}
```

Comment: Question not clear. Do you want to update the record and getting validation error for name?

Comment: if you want your `name` to be preserved with `unique` rule for validation, try to add additional rule that is being explained in [Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique).

Answer (score 1):

To update your record loop your request

```
foreach ($request as $column => $value) {
    // do something
}
```

Inside the loop check if property exist then replace if exist

```
if (property_exists($user, $column)) {
    $user->$column = $value;
}
```

So your code would be like this

```
public function update(CreateUserUpdateRequest $request, $id){
    $user = User::find($id);

    foreach ($request as $column => $value) {
        if (property_exists($user, $column)) {
            $user->$column = $value;
        }
    }

    if ($user->isDirty()) {
        $user->save();
        Session::flash('userUpdateOK', 'Dane użytkonika zostały zaktualizowane poprawnie.');
    }

    return redirect('user');
}
```

or you can just `Model::set(array())`

```
public function update(CreateUserUpdateRequest $request, $id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->set($request);

    if ($user->isDirty()) {
        $user->save();
        Session::flash('userUpdateOK', 'Dane użytkonika zostały zaktualizowane poprawnie.');
    }

    return redirect('user');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Function 'unique:users' clocked me update records where I not changed login ("name").

You have to change the validation rule a bit:

```
'name' => ['required', 'max:255', 'unique:users,name,' . $id],
```

This will ignore the uniqueness if the user is the one you're updating.

There is also another possible syntax described in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique) under "Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID".

Then you can just update normally.

As a side information, the update will only be effective if there are actual changes, otherwise the `updated_at` column won't change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over-complicating this.

You can check the row exists in the user table and then just update the relevant fields -

```
$User = User::where('name', $request->input('name'))->first();

if($User){
    $User->email = $request->input('email');
    $User->save();
}

return redirect('user')
```

The Laravel `save()` function runs the `isDirty()` function and ensures that the database will only get updated if any of the columns have changed.

Comment: `updated_at` column only updated when something is actually updated in row.

Answer (score 0):

Also `$user->column = $value;` should be `$user->$column = $value;` missing the `$` before the column variable