# Send a email only if a users updates profile with new data. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

My application gives employees of a company the ability to edit their data(example: address). Once they change any of it, a manager gets an e-mail with their new information. The problem is that an email is sent every time a employee clicks update. I need the application to compare the info in the database and only send an email if there's new information. What is good way to achieve this? **I am sorry I forgot to mention, the email needs to contain only the new iformation. So isDirty() would not work for me.**

```
public function editcredentials_action(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $address = $user->address;

    $this->validate($request, [
        'password' => 'max:255',
        'language' => 'integer',
        'facebook_profile' => 'max:255',
        'twitter_profile'  => 'max:255',

        'street'       => 'max:255',
        'house_number' => 'max:255',
        'city'         => 'max:255',
        'zip_code'     => 'max:255',
        'country'      => 'max:255',
    ]);


    if (!empty($request->get('password')) && $request->get('password')) {
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    }
    $user->facebook_profile = $request->get('facebook_profile');
    $user->twitter_profile = $request->get('twitter_profile');
    $user->language_id = $request->get('language');
    $user->save();

    if (!$address) {
        $address = new UserAddress();
        $address->user_id = $user->id;
    }
    $address->street = $request->street;
    $address->house_number = $request->house_number;
    $address->city = $request->city;
    $address->zip_code = $request->zip_code;
    $address->country = $request->country;
    $address->save();

    $data = [
        'email'    => $user->email,
        'facebook' => $user->facebook_profile,
        'twitter'  => $user->twitter_profile,
        'name'     => $user->name . ' ' . $user->lastname,
        'address'  => $address,
    ];


    Mail::send('emails.user-update', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('no-reply@example.com', 'Profile change');
        $message->to('profilechange@example.com');
        $message->subject('Profile change: ' . $data['name']);
    });


    Session::flash('message', trans('app.global.saved'));
    return back();
    //return redirect()->route('profile.edit-credentials');
}
```

Comment: You can use isDirty function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36330079/4771277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `isDirty()` will work here, but you can save user data in the beginning:

```
$params = ['language', 'facebook_profile', 'twitter_profile', 'name'];
$oldUserData = auth()->user()->only($paramsToCOmpare);
```

Then compare the data after using `save()` method:

```
if (count(array_diff($oldUserData, $user->only($paramsToCompare))) > 0) {
    // Data was changed.
}
```

You can do the same for `UserAddress` model. For password just check if it was filled in the form (since you're not displaying it anyway):

```
if (!empty($request->password))
```

Comment: why shoulnt work isDirty? Just before save() check if is dirty, and then send mail if so.