# Laravel - Check if a value of a column was changed

Tags: laravel, function, validation, methods

Imagine that I have a table named "Users" that has attributes named as; id, username, password

Is there an available function for Laravel to check if an attribute value has changed for the if statement?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I wanted to somehow let the system know what attribute changed

Comment: If you use time stamp then you can check `created_at` and `updated_at` column value to check values are updated or not.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add that I wanted to somehow let the system know what attribute changed. Is there still a way?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way in laravel. For such case you need to track all activity in the user table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function isDirty for that in Laravel.

Eloquent provides the isDirty, isClean, and wasChanged methods to examine the internal state of your model and determine how its attributes have changed from when the model was originally retrieved.

The isDirty method determines if any of the model's attributes have been changed since the model was retrieved. You may pass a specific attribute name or an array of attributes to the isDirty method to determine if any of the attributes are "dirty". The isClean method will determine if an attribute has remained unchanged since the model was retrieved. This method also accepts an optional attribute argument:

```
use App\Models\User;
 
$user = User::create([
    'first_name' => 'Taylor',
    'last_name' => 'Otwell',
    'title' => 'Developer',
]);
 
$user->title = 'Painter';
 
$user->isDirty(); // true
$user->isDirty('title'); // true
$user->isDirty('first_name'); // false
$user->isDirty(['first_name', 'title']); // true
 
$user->isClean(); // false
$user->isClean('title'); // false
$user->isClean('first_name'); // true
$user->isClean(['first_name', 'title']); // false
 
$user->save();
 
$user->isDirty(); // false
$user->isClean(); // true
```

The wasChanged method determines if any attributes were changed when the model was last saved within the current request cycle. If needed, you may pass an attribute name to see if a particular attribute was changed:

```
$user = User::create([
    'first_name' => 'Taylor',
    'last_name' => 'Otwell',
    'title' => 'Developer',
]);
 
$user->title = 'Painter';
 
$user->save();
 
$user->wasChanged(); // true
$user->wasChanged('title'); // true
$user->wasChanged(['title', 'slug']); // true
$user->wasChanged('first_name'); // false
$user->wasChanged(['first_name', 'title']); // true
```

Similar question was posted here:

[Laravel 5 isDirty() always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329850/laravel-5-isdirty-always-returns-false)

Comment: Wow! Good thing you shared that with me, haha. I'll be able to test more algorithms. Thank you! :)