# Laravel Eloquent $model->save() not saving but no error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

When updating my `Post` model, I run:

```
$post->title = request('title');
$post->body = request('body');

$post->save();
```

This does *not* update my post. But it should according to [the Laravel docs on updating Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates). **Why is my model not being updated?**

- I get no errors.
- The post does not get updated in the db.
- Besides not being updated in the db, nothing else seems odd. No errors. Behavior as normal.
- Result of [running this test to see if `save` succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877948/check-if-laravel-model-got-saved-or-query-got-executed) was `true`.
- [This Laravel thread](https://laravel.io/forum/09-08-2014-save-function-doesnt-work-and-does-not-output-an-error) was no help

`Post` model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'title',
        'body',
        'user_id',
    ];

   ....
}
```

`Post` controller:

```
public function store($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    // Request validation
    if ($post->type == 1) {
        // Post type has title
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'title' => 'required|min:15',
            'body' => 'required|min:19',
        ]);

        $post->title = request('title');
        $post->body = request('body');
    } else {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'body' => 'required|min:19',
        ]);

        $post->body = request('body');
    }

    $post->save();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

### Bonus info

Running `dd($post->save())` returns `true`.

Running

```
$post->save();

$fetchedPost = Post::find($post->id);
dd($fetchedPost);
```

shows me that `$fetchedPost` is the same post as before *without* the updated data.

Comment: are you sure you have the "body" field under POST model ?

Comment: @MoeenBasra yes, sorry! I had cleaned up the other code to make it more readable and relevant (took out irrelevant parts like code cleaning that I've already validated, etc.) and I forgot to change that variable.

Comment: What does return `dd($post->save())`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova `dd($post->save())` returns `true`. I added this in the question.

Comment: I guess laravel 5.5 change some validation system. I'm adding an answer try that.

Comment: What `dd($post->isDirty())` return?

Comment: Are you 100% certain you're looking at the right database?

Comment: I think the problem is you are not accepting the request sent from the form in the store function. @jacob

Comment: @AndersonAndrade it returned `false` ...... I followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329850/laravel-5-isdirty-always-returns-false) to ensure I was doing it right.

Comment: `request` should be `$request`?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes. I ran tests to check.

Comment: both $request injected to the store function or request helper returns the same thing. As request is binded  with singleton pattern with container.

Comment: if validation isn't the issue here too your `request('title')` and/or `request('body')` must be identical?

Comment: @LarsMertens just ran this test: Original title: **This is my title**. `dd(request('title'))`: **This is my title and now it has been updated**.

Comment: How do the post types come into it?  If the post type does not equal 1, then you are not setting the `title` however it is a `required` field.

Comment: @kerrin if the post type is not 1 then `title` is not required

Comment: Please check either you have set mutator in your model class or there is no id in model object?

Comment: What worked for me was setting a protected property $primaryKey in my model.

Comment: Make sure your Post model is extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model. I was extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot and had the same problem as yours.

Comment: put the rest of your code, how did you find the $ post? because there we can arrive at a conclusion, depending on the way the search can not use save.

Answer (score 23):

Check your database table if the 'id' column is in uppercase 'ID'. Changing it to lower case allowed my save() method to work.

Comment: You don't have to change it. You could just define the primary key name in your model by adding `protected $primaryKey = 'Id';` to your model. this in case the primary key is "Id" not "id"

Comment: This was my issue, I am working on a database that existed and ids are not called Id or ID but a completely different thing.
What makes this hard to catch is that I am using 
   ` protected $primaryKey = 'myid'; `
And it is working fine for querying, but if it isn't an exact match, it won't save, the ID of my table was in upper case, changed it and voila, problem solved, your comment opened up my eyes.

Comment: Damn MSSQL NON CASE SENSITIVE! Find the Model but Eloquent cannot save correctly.

Comment: instead of changing from db change value from `protected $primaryKey = 'Id'; ` model

Comment: my mysql USER_ID was capitalized, but I set $primaryKey = 'user_id'. Everything worked perfectly, except it would NOT save to the database. Uppercasing it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

I had the same and turned out to be because I was filtering the output columns without the primary key.

```
$rows = MyModel::where('...')->select('col2', 'col3')->get();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $rows->viewed = 1;
    $rows->save();
}
```

Fixed with

```
$rows = MyModel::where('...')->select('primary_key', 'col2', 'col3')->get();
```

Makes perfect sense on review, without the primary key available the update command will be on Null.

Comment: This was the cause of the issue for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: This got me too. Have to be sure to include the primary key in the model in order to update it with `save()`. Never knew that.

Comment: yeap, this was my problem, forgot the primary key as well :) thank!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and changing the way I fetch the model solved it!

Was not saving even though everything was supposedly working just as you have mentioned:

```
$user = User::find($id)->first();
```

This is working:

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

Comment: remembering that it is functional to use the find method together with the save, but with some others the save does not work ... also remembering that find only uses the primaryKey

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure that the instance that you are calling `save()` on has the attribute `id`

Comment: On the code shown, he is doing `$post = Post::findOrFail($id);`, so it must have an id set

Answer (score 4):

Since Laravel 5.5 laravel have change some validation mechanism I guess you need to try this way.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $validatedData = [];

    // Request validation
    if ($post->type == 1) {
        // Post type has title
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
          'title' => 'required|min:15',
          'body' => 'required|min:19',
      ]);
    } else {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required|min:19',
    ]);
    }

    $post->update($validatedData);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: can you past the dump of ```$validatedData``` just before ```$post->update()```;

Answer (score 4):

Running `dd()` inside a `DB::transaction` will cause a rollback, and the data in database will not change.

The reason being, that transaction will only save the changes to the database at the very end. Ergo, the act of running "dump and die" will naturally cause the script to cease and no therefore no database changes.

Answer (score 3):

Check your table if primary key is not id ("column name should be in small letters only") if you have set column name with different key then put code in your Model like this

```
protected $primaryKey   = 'Id';
```

So this might be one of the possible solution in your case also if your column name contains capital letters.
Yes this worked for me fine,
You should have column names in small letter,
If you don't have then mention it in the model file, mainly for primaryKey by which your model will try to access database.

Answer (score 2):

For use **save ()** method to **update** or **delete** if the database has a primary key other than "id". need to declare the attribute **primaryKey** = "" in the model, it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you using transactions.
Do not forget call **`DB::commit();`**

It must look like this:

```
try{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    // Model changes
    $model->save();
    DB::commit();
}catch (\PDOException $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue although there are `try / catch` block in `controller@action()` but there were no response, it just stops at `$model->save();` there is no log entry either in apache `error.log` or `laravel.log`. I have just wrapped the `save()` with `try / cactch` as follows, that helped me to figure out the issue

```
    try{
        $model->save();
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from the database containing multiple results for the query involving Laravel Model.

What I'm trying to convey is that if you use methods like find, findOrFail, or any other query followed by ->first(), you'll obtain one of the records, but it's almost certain that there's at least one more record that matches the query. I understand my response might be somewhat delayed, but it could potentially assist others encountering the same problem.

To resolve this, consider adding additional criteria to your query to ensure that you receive only one result as a response. This step will help guarantee accurate outcomes.

Comment: Thank you. You also need to make sure the primary key is in the select statement if you're using one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function store($id,Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    // Request validation
    if ($post->type == 1) {
        // Post type has title
         $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:15',
            'body' => 'required|min:19',
        ]);
        $post->update([
              'title' => request('title');
              'body' => request('body');
             ]);
    } else {
         $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|min:19',
        ]);

        $post->update([
              'body' => request('body');
             ]);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you select an Eloquent model from the db and the `primary_key` column is not part of the fetched columns, your `$model->save()` will return true but nothing is persisted to the database.

So, instead of doing `\App\Users::where(...)->first(['email'])`, rather do `\App\Users::where(...)->first(['id','email'])`, where `id` is the `primary_key` defined on the target table.

If the (sometimes micro-optimization) achieved by retrieving only a few columns is not really of importance to you, you can just fetch all columns by doing `\App\Users::where(...)->first()`, in which case you do not need to bother about the name of the `primary_key` column since all the columns will be fetched.

Answer (score -1):

I have been experiencing the same issue and found a workaround. I found that I was unable to `save()` my model within a function called `{{ generateUrl() }}` on my `home.blade.php` template. What worked was moving the `save()` call to the controller that `return`s the `home.blade.php` template. (IE, `save()`ing before the view is `return`ed, then only performing read operations within `{{ generateUrl() }}`.)

I was (and am) generating a `state` to put in a URL on page load:

```
<!--views/home.blade.php-->

<a href="{{ EveAuth::generateUrl() }}">Add Character</a>
```

**Below is what did not work.**

```
// Providers/EveAuth.php

function generateUrl()
{
    $authedUser = auth()->user();
    if (!$authedUser) {
        return "#";
    }
    $user = User::find($authedUser->id);
    $user->state = str_random(16);
    $user->save();

    $baseUrl = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize?state=';

    return $baseUrl . $user->state;
}
```

This was able to `find()` the `User` from the database, but it was unable to `save()` it back. No errors were produced. The function appeared to work properly... until I tried to read the `User`'s `state` later, and found that it did not match the `state` in the URL.

**Here is what did work.**

Instead of trying to `save()` my `User` as the page was being assembled, I generated the `state`, `save()`d it, then rendered the page:

```
// routes/web.php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Landing at the root directory sends you to the `index()` function of `HomeController.php`:

```
// Controllers/HomeController.php

public function index()
{
    $authedUser = auth()->user();
    if ($authedUser) {
        $user = User::find($authedUser->id);
        $user->state = str_random(16);
        $user->save();
    }
    return view('home');
}
```

Then, when generating the URL, I did not have to `save()` the `User`, only read from it:

```
// Providers/EveAuth.php

function generateUrl()
{
    $authedUser = auth()->user();
    $user = User::find($authedUser->id);

    $baseUrl = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize?state=';

    return $baseUrl . $user->state;
}
```

This worked! The only difference (as far as I see) is that I'm `save()`ing the model before page assembly begins, as opposed to during page assembly.