# Laravel how to update value in mysql only if value is changed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm new to Laravel. All I'm trying to do is as follow:

I have some fields in my form like **TITLE, DESCRIPTION**.

**TITLE** field is unique in database.

This is what I've done to update my values.

```
$product              = Product::find($id); 
$product->title       = $request->title;
$product->description = $request->description;
$product->save();
```

But this will give error (that value already exists) as my **TITLE** field is unique.

All I want to is update my **TITLE** only if the **TITLE** value is changed otherwise update the same value but update other fields. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866500/laravel-eloquent-update-just-if-changes-have-been-made this might help you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$product = Product::find($id);

if ($product->title == $request->title) {
    $product->description = $request->description;
} else {
    $product->title = $request->title;
}

$product->save();
```

Comment: I want to update specific row which is given by id. I think above function will change any row whose title matches. It is so.Thanks

Comment: Please check updated answer. You'll get the row from DB. Then you'll check if title had changed. If title was changed, it'll update title only. If not, it'll update description only. Is this behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does exactly (if indirectly) what you say you want. Your problem is another: **you're assigning a title that is used elsewhere**, thereby violating uniqueness.

You must verify that the **new** title is not already used.

```
$duplicate = Product::where('title', '=', $request->title)->where('id', '!=', $id)->first();
```

At this point **it is unclear what you want to do**:

a) Do you want to use the duplicate record *instead* of the one indicated by `$id`?

b) Is this an error?

c) Should the `$id` record be updated, leaving the title alone?

You can do any of these things; what you **can't** do is "update my TITLE only if the TITLE value is changed", because the changed value is already in use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any of your database structure or form code only the small snippet above you have stated.

you could do something like this...

```
$checkTitle = Product::where('title', '=', $request->input('title')->first();
```

You can also do...

```
   $record = Product::find($id)

    if($request->input('title') === $record->title){
     // Record with the $id has the same title as you are posting in the request.
    }else{
         // Title for $id lets say id number 3, Is not the same as the form request you are sending so now Perform insert
      }


   if(count($checkTitle) >= 1){
      // Means the title exists and do what ever you want...
     //  Perform update
    }else{
      // Perform insert
     }
```

Sorry for short and sweet, leaving to go to office and thought it might help to post now. Let me know if im on the wrong tracks and ill help where i can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` statement to check weather column value is same with original?

```
$currentProduct         = Product::find($id);
//Check and update if title not same
if($currentProduct->title == $request->title){
    $currentProduct->description   = $request->description;   
}
//Update title and description...
else {
    $currentProduct->title         = $request->title;
    $currentProduct->description   = $request->description;
} 

$currentProduct->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at wasChanged() function in Laravel.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or info about this wasChanged function? I've looked everywhere and I'm unable to find anything.

Comment: Here you go - https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_isDirty