# Laravel: How to verify if model was changed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Is there a simple way for the [Eloquent save method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) to check if a row has actually changed? Something like `affected_rows` for Eloquent?

The only workaround that I found was from [Laravel Eloquent update just if changes have been made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866500/laravel-eloquent-update-just-if-changes-have-been-made) to do:

```
$user = Auth::user();

$timestamp = $user->updated_at;

$user->title = $request->input('title');
....

$user->save();

if($timestamp == $user->updated_at){
   // row was not updated.
}
```

But is this possible to find this out shorter, without the need of a `$timestep` variable and the check? I don't want to repeat that logic in every controller.

I am looking for something like this:

```
$user = Auth::user();

$user->title = $request->input('title');
....

if($user->save()){
   // row was updated.
}
```

But this does not work since `$user->save` returns `true` in both cases.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all instead of:

```
$user->save
```

you should rather use:

```
$user->save();
```

And to verify if anything was changes in latest Laravel you can use:

```
if ($user->wasChanged()) {
    // do something
}
```

but be aware this is as far as I remember in Laravel 5.5

Comment: Yes thank you I corrected it. I tried it and it works. One has to call `$user->save()` before `$user->wasChanged()`.

Comment: @Adam Yes, you normally run `$user->save()` and you can then run `$user->wasChanged()` to verify if it was changed. If you wanted to verify what was changed you have also method `getChanges()`

Answer (score 3):

You could also skip the save altogether and check if your model `->isDirty()`, before calling `->save()` at all.

```
// ...
$user->title = $request->input('title');

if ($user->isDirty()) {
    $user->save();
}
```

Besides `isDirty()`, you also have `isClean()`, and more.

Check out: [HasAttributes trait](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_isDirty)

Comment: Actually Laravel makes this check itself, before saving it checks if any changes have been done by calling isDirty(), if it returns false, no update is made.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `update()` to update the records...

```
$user = Auth::user();
$userUpdated = $user->update($request->all());

//Print number of updated rows...
print($userUpdated);
```

This will show you the number of affected rows...

Comment: In Laravel 5.6, `$user->update($request->all())` returns *true*