# Dirty Methods in Rails equivalent in PHP Codeignitor

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am new to PHP & `Codeigniter` but it was needed some kind of implementation in PHP.

Following are [dirty methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) are provided in rails framework by default, here `person` is model object representing row inside `persons` table.

```
person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed?       # => true
person.name_changed?  # => true
person.name_changed?(from: nil, to: "Bob") # => true
person.name_was       # => nil
person.name_change    # => [nil, "Bob"]
person.name = 'Bill'
person.name_change    # => [nil, "Bill"]
```

I am interested in `to` & `from` specially, Please suggest whether it is possible with any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would consider Laravel's elquent framework you have a great deal of that functionality already.

[Laravel Eloquent update just if changes have been made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866500/laravel-eloquent-update-just-if-changes-have-been-made)

It holds an array of the "original" values in the Model, and if any of them have been changed it will commit them to the database.

They also come with a lot of events you can plug into(beforeSave, afterSave, beforeCreate, afterCreate, validation rules, etc...) and they can be extended easily. It might be the closest compatible thing I can imagine you're looking for.

This is however not codeigniter, it relies on a different framework. If you're not dead set on codeigniter you might consider switching to a framework like Laravel or OctoberCMS depending on your needs.

**Edit because you're stuck with codeigniter**

You might wish to use a library like this one: https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-model

It is then very easy to extend with some custom caching mechanisms.

The code below is something you could use as a basis for your own model implementation.

It has a very rudementary logic basis, but allows you to check on the dirty status and roll back any changes made to the model.

Note this this is very rudementary, and might even contain a few errors because I have not run this code. it's more a proof of concept to help you create a model that suits your needs.

```
class User extends CI_Model 
{

     public $table = 'users';

     public $primaryKey = 'id';

     public $attributes;

     public $original;

     public $dirty = [];

     public $exists = false;

     function __construct() 
     {
         parent::Model();

     }

     public static function find($model_id) 
     {
         $static = new static;
         $query = $static->db->query("SELECT * FROM ' . $static->getTable() . ' WHERE ' . $this->getKeyName() . ' = ?", [$model_id]);
         if($result->num_rows()) {
            $static->fill($query->row_array());
            $static->exists = true;
         }
         else {
             return null;
         }
         return $static;
     }

     public function getKeyName() 
     {
         return $this->primaryKey;   
     }

     public function getKey() 
     {
        return $this->getAttribute($this->getKeyName());  
     }

     public function getTable()
     {
         return $this->table;
     }

     public function fill($attributes) 
     {
         if(is_null($this->original)) {
             $this->original = $attributes;
             $this->dirty = $attributes;
         }
         else {
             foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
                 if($this->original[$key] != $value) {
                     $this->dirty[$key] = $value;
                 }
             }
         }
         $this->attributes = $attributes;
     }

     public function reset() 
     {
         $this->dirty = [];
         $this->attributes = $this->original;
     }

     public function getAttribute($attribute_name) 
     {
        return array_key_exists($attribute_name, $this->attributes) ? $this->attributes[$attribute_name] : null;    
     }

     public function __get($key) 
     {
        return $this->getAttribute($key);    
     }

     public function __set($key, $value)
     {
         $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
     }

     public function setAttribute($key, $value) 
     {
         if(array_key_exists($key, $this->original)) {
             if($this->original[$key] !== $value) {
                $this->dirty[$key] = $value;
             }
         }
         else {
             $this->original[$key] = $value;
             $this->dirty[$key] = $value;
         }

         $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
     }

     public function getDirty() 
     {
        return $this->dirty;    
     }

     public function isDirty() 
     {
        return (bool)count($this->dirty);    
     }

     public function save() 
     {
         if($this->isDirty()) {
             if($this->exists) 
             {
                 $this->db->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());
                 $this->db->update($this->getTable(), $this->getDirty());

                 $this->dirty = [];
                 $this->original = $this->attributes;
             }
             else 
             {
                 $this->db->insert($this->getTable(), $this->getDirty());

                 $this->dirty = [];
                 $this->original = $this->attributes;

                 $this->attributes[$this->getKeyName()] = $this->db->insert_id();
                 $this->original[$this->getKeyName()] = $this->getKey();
                 $this->exists = true;
             }

         }
     }
 }

 if($user = User::find(1)) {
      $user->name = "Johnny Bravo";
      $user->save();
 }
```

Comment: I will surely prefer rails over any php framework but I have requirement in existing application which is on code igniter.

Comment: What can I say but my sympathies. I'll edit my answer to add some codeigniter magic ish.

Comment: Check if possible with `start_cache` and `stop_cache` prior and later to `$this->db->update` in MyModel and later if possible may get changes..

Comment: @ray I updated my answer. Can you take a look at it if it suits your needs more? Take note of the dirty variable that will allow you to check changes within the model since last fetch from the database.