# Ability to tell if a model for CRUD controller has been updated using Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using a Backpack for Laravel CRUD controller and I'm trying to figure out if there's an efficient way to tell if a Model has been updated without loading both the current model and the updated model and then comparing attribute values.

Comment: The simplest way might be to use Laravel's [model observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events) functionality. Or, you could override the model's `save` method and use the `isDirty('columnName')` method to inspect changes as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866500/laravel-eloquent-update-just-if-changes-have-been-made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the suggestion in the comment and overrode the save() method on my model as such.

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{

     // Update the mode accordingly and perform any 
     // other actions you need to prior to saving here.

     $saved = parent::save($options);
     return $saved;
 }
```