# The Laravel $model->save() response?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

If you are thinking this question is a beginner's question, maybe you are right. But really I was confused.

In my code, **I want to know if saving a model is successful or not.**

```
$model = Model::find(1);
$model->attr = $someVale;
$saveStatus = $model->save()
```

So, I think `$saveStatus` must show me if the saving is successful or not, But, **now, the model is saved in the database while the `$saveStatus` value is NULL.**

I am using **Laravel 7**;

Comment: Give a complete description of how you are calling the model

Comment: After calling the save method on your object, is it in your database?

Comment: @Peppermintology Yeah, It was saved successfully, And I have got no error, but the save response is NULL.

Comment: Are you using any additional traits or anything in your model that might also have a save method that is conflicting?

Comment: @Peppermintology wtf, In our projects, developers extend the modified laravel-rest-API Model. And I think my problem was there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`save()` will return a boolean, saved or not saved. So you can either do:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->attr = $value;
$saved = $model->save();
if(!$saved){
    //Do something
}
```

Or directly save in the if:

```
if(!$model->save()){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But, in my case boolean does not returns, I am getting just Null. And I am confused because of that.

Comment: You can try to see what the result is from Model::find(1) by doing dd($model) after line 1 and see whether you are getting a null value there

Answer (score 1):

Please read those documentation from Laravel api section.

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getChanges

From here you can get many option to know current object was modified or not.

Also you can check this,

[Laravel Eloquent update just if changes have been made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866500/laravel-eloquent-update-just-if-changes-have-been-made)

For Create object,
those option can helpful,

You can check the public attribute $exists on your model

```
if ($model->exists) {
// Model exists in the database
}
```

You can check for the models id (since that's only available after the record is saved and the newly created id is returned)

```
if(!$model->id){
App::abort(500, 'Some Error');
}
```